# How to add "previous" and "next" button to text lightbox/modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, lightbox

I am partially rendering data from an endpoint in a list using underscore, each list item has a link to "learn more...". Clicking on that link opens up a text modal/lightbox that shows the rest of the info for that particular element. I would like to add prev and next arrows to see the additional info on the items on the list, without having to close the modal and click on the next item.

I am thinking the way to approach this would be to add a class of "current" to my selected element, and remove/assign this class to each element as needed. But I am stuck thinking how to go about this... (newbie here, be kind).

HTML

```
<script type="text/template" id="event-template">
  <div class="event row no-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-12 info">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <p class="day"><%= day %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <%= month %> at <%= time %>, <%= storename %> <br> <%= city %> <%= state %>

            <a class="show-panel" data-id=<%=entry_id%> href="#_"> Learn More...</a>
        </div>

        <div class="lightbox-panel" id="lightbox-panel-<%=entry_id%>">
            <h2><%= storename %></h2>
            <p><%= month %>, <%= desc %></p>

            <p align="center"><a class="close-panel" href="#_">Close window</a></p>

            <div class="col-md-10" id="prev"><a href="#_">Previous</a></div>
            <div class="col-md-2" id="next"><a href="#_">Next</a></div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

JS

```
// Open lightbox
$("#events-placeholder").on("click", ".show-panel", function(e) {
    var entry_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $("#lightbox-panel-"+entry_id).fadeIn(300);
     $("body").css("background-color", "black");
});

//Close lightbox
$("#events-placeholder").on("click", "#close-panel", function(e) {
    $(".lightbox-panel").fadeOut(300);
    $("body").css("background-color", "white");
});

// Prev Info
$(".events-placeholder").on("click", "#prev", function(e) {
    // ???
    var current = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var previous = current - 1;
    $("#lightbox-panel-"+entry_id-1).fadeIn(300);


});

// Next Info
$("#events-placeholder").on("click", "#next", function(e) {
// ???

});
```